# attribute selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to select element by attribute with code below

```
$('dt[data-panel="2"] h2').html();
```

but this doesn't work for

```
<dl>
    <dt data-panel="panel-2">
        <h2 class="delta expandable">Text</h2>
    </dt>
</dl>
```

am I missing something?

fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/u1offsyw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the attribute is `panel-2`, not just `2`, hence your selector needs to be:

```
$('dt[data-panel="panel-2"] h2').html();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u1offsyw/1/)